# CakePHP Password reset not changing password

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following function in a CakePHP 1.3 app that takes a token and allows the user to change their password. Everything seems to work fine except that the password doesn't actually get changed :/ Any ideas what the problem is?

```
function admin_changepassword ( $token = null )
    {
        // If has a token or form has been submitted
        if (!empty($token) || !(empty($this->data)))
        {   
            $user = $this->User->find('first',array("MD5(User.email + '".Configure::read('Security.salt')."')"=>$token));

            if (empty($user))
            { 
                $this->redirect(array('admin'=>false,'controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','home'));
                $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid token'); 
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set('user',$user);
                if (!empty($this->data['User']['password']))
                { 
                    $user['User']['password'] = $this->data['User']['password']; 
                    $this->User->save($this->data); 
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your password has been changed! Please log in.'); 
                    $this->redirect(array('admin'=>true,'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect(array('admin'=>false,'controller'=>'home','action'=>'display','home'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('No token');
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're asking your database to hash every single password of every user for comparison with that query, potentially a hugely wasteful operation.

Comment: Can you explain this further as I don't understand and is that the reason for the password not being changed?

Comment: You're querying `WHERE MD5(password...) = 'somestring'`. This means the database needs to perform `MD5(password...)` on every row so it can compare it to `'somestring'`. What is this token supposed to be anyway? I don't think that's your problem though. What *is* your problem exactly? What does it do?

Comment: it doesnt change the password in the db even though it shows the flash

Comment: You aren't setting the `id` of what to update; unless I'm mistaken. I believe cake will create another record if `$Model->id` isn't set.

Comment: How are you storing the passwords? Unless you're ensuring that passwords are unique in your database, your token method does not guarantee that you're actually changing the password of the right user!

Comment: Well I'm the only user at the moment so it's doesn't matter but I've changed it to use email instead of password for the token but it still doesn't change my password :/ Could you perhaps show an amended version of my code that'd solve my problem?

Comment: Is this code and problem linked to croogo as you report it in your workaround answer ? I think there is a bug in croogo that makes impossible to change the password of the first existing user of croogo once its login (admin) has been changed. You may look into that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do something like this; but I'm assuming your user is actually logged in, using the `auth` component or similar. Untested; but logic looks like it should work to me.

```
<?php
function admin_changepassword ($token = NULL) {
    // bail out early if there is no token set, and always set the flash before redirecting.
    if($token==NULL) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('No token');
        $this->redirect(array('admin'=>false,'controller'=>'home','action'=>'display','home'));
    }

    // this is an admin action; the user already be logged in right?
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $user_password = $this->User->field('password');

    // does the token match the hashed password, and did they enter a new password?
    if($token==md5($user_password . Configure::read('Security.salt')) && !empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->User->saveField('password', $this->data['User']['password']);    
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your password has been changed! Please log in.'); 
        $this->redirect(array('admin'=>true,'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    }

    // somethings gone wrong/password was not updated
    $this->Session->setFlash('Your password was not changed.'); 
    $this->redirect(array('admin'=>false,'controller'=>'home','action'=>'display','home'));
}
```

Comment: No the user would not be logged in as they are changing their password because they have forgot it! The user is the Admin!

Comment: But my code definitely KNOWS what user I am as I show a Hello email address message on the view so it knows it just doesn't change the password :/

Comment: also `change password` is different to `forgot password`. May want to look at renaming your methods, if only for semantic reasons. Change implies the user is logged in and wishes to change their password to something new; hence I assumed your user was logged in.

Answer (score 1):

OK upon some testing, your problem is as I initially suggested in my comment.

You aren't setting the `id` of your user, so:

`$this->User->save($this->data);`

is not updating the password, it is adding a new row to your database.

You need to specify the ID of the user's to update.

```
$user = $this->User->find('first',array("MD5(User.email + 
                            '".Configure::read('Security.salt')."')"=>$token));

// this line is redundant 
$user['User']['password'] = $this->data['User']['password'];  


$this->User->id = $user['User']['id']; // set user id
$this->User->save($this->data);  //  save it
```

If you check your `users` table I suspect you will find there are lots of empty records with the "changed" password. My testing agrees with the cake manual.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but it might help someone

```
function changePwd(){
     $this->User->id = $this->data->['User']['id']; //assuming this is set
     //check if the password fields are empty
     //check if the password fields match (password and confirm password one)

    //convert password 
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password'] );

    //saveField worked for me
    if($this->User->saveField('password',$this->request->data['User']['password'])){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Password changed successfully.','flashSuccess');
    }else{ ....
}
```